# Drop down menu, full screen width, wanting to group items and cant get it working

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

Heres my work: http://jsfiddle.net/DJV3F/

As it is bootstrapped you will need to make the display screen at least 1000px wide to see accurately

I have the menu created
it populates fine

In drop down box 1 the items overlap (i tried separating them into unique ul's but the `position` css causes them to stack

Drop down box 2 is the same menu items, but without the lists separated out to see what the menu originally looks like

What I am going for is each main menu category is in a row, if there are sub categories they fall below the main category, then after 4 across it starts a new row

```
--------------------------------------
MAIN    | MAIN    | MAIN    | MAIN    
--------------------------------------
SUB     | SUB     |         | SUB     
SUB     |         |         |         
SUB     |         |         |         
SUB     |         |         |         
======================================
MAIN    | MAIN    | MAIN              
--------------------------------------
SUB     | SUB     |         |         
SUB     | SUB     |         |
```

What I am getting is haphazard staggering, not sure where in the code to make the change to either make the first menu list elements not stack on top of each other (dynamic, so number of items may not always be the same, so no coding in hard number for base height), or what to change in the second example to make it work as desired

Comment: You need to use floats to position the sub-menu next to each other. Take a look at this tutorial: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/how-to-build-a-kick-butt-css3-mega-drop-down-menu/

Comment: Also - it's easier to figure things out of you stick all the typographical styling on the a-tag, with display:block (fonts, spacing, colours etc) and put the positional styling on the list elements (floats, position etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I am a backend guy (php/mysql) but got stuck on a project that involves doing this menu